# Class 'Zend Validate Ip' not found in magento

Tags: magento, zend-framework

Everything was working fine but suddenly the fatal error appeared on the server:

> Fatal Error : Class 'Zend_Validate_Ip' not found in
>   magento/lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php on line 416.

Can anybody please help me to fix that?

Comment: Are you sure your Magento install uploaded completely?

Comment: yes site was up and running till yesterday.

Comment: Hm, you may need some technical support. This is off topic on Stack Overflow, though, I'm afraid. Maybe Magento's support resources can be of more help.

Comment: on which magento version you are working?

Comment: magento one point nine

Comment: on which step you are getting this error?

Comment: check for the file `lib/Zend/Validate/Ip.php` it exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `Ip.php` file.

try to upload that file from a fresh magento in you `lib/Zend/Validate/` folder.
I think that might help you.